# Angular JS ui-router not loading view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having trouble with my Angular JS ui-router and every question I have found on here shows a solutions I have already tried.

In my ui-view-tag my actual template is not displayed.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
 .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
   function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

Thank you very much everybody, I would really appreciate a short feedback on that.

Comment: any message from the console?

Comment: no nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$urlRouterProvider` `otherwise()` accepts the **url path** you want to redirect to. Therefore, you need to change:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

To:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me try that.